# Set precision of shown attribute in autocad dynamic block

Tags: block, autocad

I made a blog that shows it current with and height in the displayed thext.
Now they have 4 decimal places (for example 5.600), see picture below.

I want them displayed with only 1 decimal place, how can i do this?
(example below would become 5.6x16.5 in stead of 5.6000x16.5000)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either modify the **Precision** property of the Field formatting so as to round the result to 1 decimal place:

[image]

Or, if you were looking to retain the precision, you could instead suppress trailing zeroes within the **Additional Format** options:

[image]

Alternatively, assuming that your formatting is set to **Current units**, you could change the value of your `LUPREC` system variable.